# Trouble parsing individual JSON elements (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

My JSON structure is below. I am very new to Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. After browsing the documentation and tinkering for quite a few hours I have been unable to figure out how to parse individual elements in this JSON structure.

```
{
  "transactions": {
     "transaction": [
        {
          "payment_id": 2,
          "payment_date": "2015-06-30",
          "url": "myurl",
          "title": "mytitle",
          "sell_id": 4,
          "last_update": "2015-06-30",
          "inventory_id": 4,
          "amount": "30.00",
          "item_id": 4682,
          "buyer_id": 1
        },
        {
          "payment_id": 1,
          "payment_date": "2015-06-29",
          "url": "myurl2",
          "title": "mytitle",
          "sell_id": 3,
          "last_update": "2015-06-29",
          "inventory_id": 3,
          "amount": "40.00",
          "item_id": 1061,
          "buyer_id": 1
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Code:

```
class func RecentTransactions() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL)
        .responseJSON { (_, _, jsonData, _) in
            println(jsonData!)
            let json = JSON(jsonData!)
    }
}
```

Comment: A library that may help in making Json reading simple.  https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/5d36646cafe9044779eb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the outer two objects are dictionaries, the inner object is an array.

Try this, it iterates thru the inner array and prints the values for the properties `title` and `url` (the dictionary keys are a bit confusing ;-) )

```
  class func RecentTransactions() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL)
      .responseJSON { (_, _, jsonData, _) in
        println(jsonData!)
        let json = JSON(jsonData!)
        let transactions = json["transactions"]
        let transaction = transactions["transaction"]
        for (index: String, action: JSON) in transaction {
          println(action["title"])
          println(action["url"])
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. Yes, they are a bit confusing as I am new to JSON structures as well.